# how give a proper input shape to my cnn model?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am creating a video classification model for which I extracted all image features and built a dataset with that. when I try to fit my code.it shows an error related to my dataset shape . I tried different shapes but nothing worked. Does anyone know about this ?

Below is the code for my CNN model .

```
model = Sequential()

#building a Cnn network
model.add(Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(18,40,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

# completing our model with a simple dense layer
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

and below is my X and y shape .

```
X - (18,40)
y - (18,)

X = Extracted_image_features + Extracted_audio_features + Extracted_text_features #array of features 

y = Image_labels + audio_labels + text_labels # [ 0, 1, 0, .... 0, 1] total 18 

model.fit(X, y, epochs=2)
```

I tried to fit my model but it showing the below error .

```
ValueError: in user code:

File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 18, 40, 1), found shape=(None, 40)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: yeah now i simplified as much as possible .

Comment: Still not reproducible though. What's `X`, what's `y`, how do you fit?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you first reshape and then create the CNN model.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical


X = np.random.rand(18, 40)  # Replace with your actual image data
y = np.random.randint(2, size=18)  # Replace with your actual labels
X = np.reshape(X, (18, 40, 1))
y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(18, 40, 1))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: yeah that also i tried but still getting error . 
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 18, 40, 1), found shape=(None, 40, 1)

Answer (score 0):

The last line of code in your model architecture is as follows:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

This line signifies that your model is designed to produce only two outputs, which correspond to class labels 0 and 1, respectively.

Regarding your shape of data

```
X - (18,40)
y - (18,)
```

It seems that your program interprets these data as 18 separate data points, where each data point contains 40 features in `X`. This interpretation is the reason you are encountering the error message with the following output: "`Expected shape=(None, 18, 40, 1), found shape=(None, 40).`"

Therefore, if your input shape is 2D (18,40), you should modify your model output layer and make sure input shape is `(batch_size, 18, 40, 1)`. If your input shape is 1D (40), you may modify the `MaxPooling2D` and `Conv2D` to `MaxPooling1D` and `Conv1D`, respectively.